# Style with CSS variables in $.each()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, google-sheets

I'm trying to add style to the link's "values" variables, but with no success. can anybody help me?

**Example of the code I'm using:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".guide").append(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10Ct44JBW-CyoApJXIV87jeVU3Rr-fiLTdoTIJdbSwG8/values/page1!A2:C3?key=AIzaSyArRlzwEZHF50y3SV-MO_vU_1KrOIfnMeI"
    
, function(result){
      $.each(result.values, function(i, field){
        $(".guide").append( '<div style="font-size: 12px;">' + field + '</div>' +'<div style="font-size: 14px;">' + field + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size: 18px;">' + field + '</div>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="guide"></div>
```

Comment: Typo? `'<div style="font-size: 12px;"' `is missing the `>` at the end... `'<div style="font-size: 12px;">' ` (all divs)

Comment: [CSS Variables/Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are a specific concept in CSS-- do you mean that you're trying to apply a style in the `style` attribute?

Comment: @GertB. - think you might have an answer on your hands...

Comment: @GertB. oh thanks, i just fixed it, but the style still doesn't work

Comment: After the edit, still wrong :-) the `>` must be after the  double quote`"`

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'm not gonna answer if it is a typo :-D

Comment: @AlexanderNied Not an answer, a close flag because this is a typo

Comment: @AlexanderNied Yes, I'm trying to add style to each of the link's "values" variables.

Comment: Fair point -- I hadn't initially conceptualized it as a typo but that makes much more sense.

Comment: Here's the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/n5hymj8p/ (note that the outer `.append()` is nonsense and was removed)

Comment: `$(".guide").append( '<div style="font-size: 12px;">' + field + '</div>' +'<div style="font-size: 14px;">' + field + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size: 18px;">' + field + '</div>');`

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'm trying to add different sizes for each number, but the result shows the string "1,2,3" three times. I'm trying to make the number "1" 12px, the number "2" 14px, and the number "3" 18px.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm trying to make the number "1" 12px, the number "2" 14px, and the number "3" 18px.

Comment: Working demo https://jsfiddle.net/bZezzz/o7gqwrjn/4/

Comment: @BrunoSilva Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of the response. It looks like it is "1,2,3". If this is the case, you need to split this string up to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Proper solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g16fxd79/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much, I learned a lot by looking at your code. Gratitude. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your data structure you **MUST** "loop" on `result.values[0]`, and store your "style" in array then access corresponding index (i) for both value et style.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".guide").append(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10Ct44JBW-CyoApJXIV87jeVU3Rr-fiLTdoTIJdbSwG8/values/page1!A2:C3?key=AIzaSyArRlzwEZHF50y3SV-MO_vU_1KrOIfnMeI"
    
, function(result){
      let style = ['12','14','18'];
      $.each(result.values[0], function(i, field){
        $(".guide").append( '<div style="font-size:'+style[i]+'px;">' + field + '</div>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="guide"></div>
```

But there is a more appropriate way to do this shared by [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g16fxd79/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/08a2rps7/11/

**HTML**

```
<div class="guide"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sm {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.rg {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.lg {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/10Ct44JBW-CyoApJXIV87jeVU3Rr-fiLTdoTIJdbSwG8/values/page1!A2:C3?key=AIzaSyArRlzwEZHF50y3SV-MO_vU_1KrOIfnMeI", function(result) {
    var classes = [
      "sm",
      "rg",
      "lg"
    ];
    $.each(result.values[0], function(i, field) {
      $(".guide").append('<span class="' + classes[i] + '">' + field + '</span>');
    });
  });
});
```

You can choose to use DIV versus SPAN yet DIV naturally Blocks where as SPAN is Inline. Your `result.values` is an Array or Arrays, therefore, `field` is an array.  You must index it properly to get each part.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. :DDD